# How to force google chrome to reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The website I'm working on allows users to delete documents. Because it uses ajax, a dialogue pops up when you click the delete button, then requiring you to hit confirm. The plug-in I use for the dialogue then calls a function which should first send the ajax request and then reload the page.

For some reason, the page never truly reloads. It seems to be getting data from the cache. I have tried all the solutions I could find online and on stack overflow, but none of them force it to refresh. Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little details here to work from, so I will guess.

Plugin is not using `window.location.reload()` but it just sets window location to some url with `window.location = '/somepath'` that has already been fetched.
Make sure that the url it's loading returns no-cache headers from server side and no ETag headers.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires:  <time that is in past>
```

Alternative change the plugin to add some random parameter on the url

```
window.location = '/somepath?=' + (+new Date());
```